# angular cant use on toggle action for same tag

Tags: angular, typescript

I want to implement a group of toggle button like code below but when select one of them all is selected and opposed
my code is:

**html:**

```
<div class="factor-box">
          <div (click)="onSelect($event, 1)" class="default" [class.selected]="isToggled" id="price">price</div>
          <div (click)="onSelect($event, 2)" class="default" [class.selected]="isToggled" id="discount">discount</div>
          <div (click)="onSelect($event, 3)" class="default" [class.selected]="isToggled" id="response">response</div>
          <div (click)="onSelect($event, 4)" class="default" [class.selected]="isToggled" id="viewCount">viewCount</div>
          <div (click)="onSelect($event, 5)" class="default" [class.selected]="isToggled" id="acceptance">acceptance</div>
 </div>
```

**ts:**

```
    isToggled: boolean;

    onSelect(event) {
        this.isToggled = !this.isToggled;
    }
```

**scss:**

```
        .default {
          height: 36px;
          border-radius: 10px;
          border: solid 1px #e8e8e8;
          background-color: #ffffff;
          color: #646464;
          display: flex;
          align-items: center;
          justify-content: center;
          padding: 0px 13px;
          cursor: pointer;
        }
        .selected {
          background-color: #ffe5ec;
          color: #ed1459;
          border-color: #ffe5ec;
        }
```

**When I select a button, I need to change the color of the button and announce its ID**

Answer (score 0):

I have done the same thing using below code.

```js
isValue: number = 24;  
onClickTime(time) {
    this.isValue = time;
  }
```

```html
     <button mat-flat-button class="basic_button" [ngClass]="{ 'active' : isValue == 1 }" (click)="onClickTime(1)">1 Hour</button>
            <button mat-flat-button class="basic_button" [ngClass]="{ 'active' : isValue == 6 }" (click)="onClickTime(6)">6 Hours</button>
            <button mat-flat-button class="basic_button" [ngClass]="{ 'active' : isValue == 12 }" (click)="onClickTime(12)">12 Hours</button>
            <button mat-flat-button class="basic_button" [ngClass]="{ 'active' : isValue == 24 }" (click)="onClickTime(24)">24 Hours</button>
```

Comment: yes it will show the error here because the editor of the site does not have angular.

Comment: where you use selected class name?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that everyone relies on the same attribute: class.selected
So when the attribute changes everyone will change 
try instead:

```
onSelect(event) {
    this.isToggled = !this.isToggled;
}
```

write:

```
onSelect(event) {
    var classes=event.target.classList;
    if(classes.contains("selected"))
      classes.remove("selected");
    else
      classes.add("selected");
}
```

delete from divs:

```
[class.selected]="isToggled"
```

Comment: with your solution how to deselect?? isn't toggle right?

Comment: I try to implement your code but doesn't change color and background when select

Comment: i change my solution. try again.
dont make change in css file only in onSelect func

Comment: thanks on your comment i change my solution in onSelect func. try again.

Answer (score 0):

this solution work's for me
** change ts file:**

```
 onSelect(event) {
    this.isToggled = !this.isToggled;
    if (this.isToggled) {
      event.target.classList.add("selected");
    } else {
      event.target.classList.remove("selected");
    }
  }
```

**remove from html**

```
[class.selected]="isToggled"
```